# Cant see the Marker or Zoom in GoogleMap in SupportMapFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-maps, android-maps-v2, android-support-library

I have a SupportMapFragment that I want  to add a simple marker to but for some reason I cant see it on the map...I dont see any error in the logcat either any idea?

```
public class MapUserFragment extends SupportMapFragment
{

    private GoogleMap googleMap;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_fragment_layout, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        googleMap = getMap();
        if (googleMap != null)
        {
            try
            {

                googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(27.174840, 78.042500)).title("Hello World")
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_drawer)));

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
<fragment
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
map:uiCompass="true"
map:mapType= "normal"
map:uiRotateGestures="true"
map:uiScrollGestures="true"
map:uiTiltGestures="true"
map:uiZoomControls="true"
map:uiZoomGestures="true" 
/>
```

google-play-services_lib manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

package="com.google.android.gms"
android:versionCode="3159130"
android:versionName="3.1.59 (744626-30)" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"/>
```

MyManifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.tailgate"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
<!-- GCM connects to Google Services. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

<!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.tailgate.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<!--
 Creates a custom permission so only this app can receive its messages.

 NOTE: the permission *must* be called PACKAGE.permission.C2D_MESSAGE,
       where PACKAGE is the application's package name.
-->
<permission
    android:name="com.tailgate.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />


<!-- Location permission -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.location"
    android:required="true" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.location.gps"
    android:required="false" />

<application
    android:name=".TailGateApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyCKHkansQagp34Q5hiEEDm5XMPhT_Izntc" />
</application>
```

Edit:

I also cant zoom into a certain LatLong

```
    LatLng cur_Latlng =new LatLng(31.763160705566406, 35.20343017578125);
            googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(cur_Latlng));
            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10)); 
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Is `getMap()` returning `null`?

Comment: are you sure googleMap is not null?

Comment: no googlemap is not null...

Comment: Check the result of BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource. Check if it's null

Comment: resource is not null . I also tried removing icon..

Answer (score 2):

Found the soltution below:

However I dont know why this is? Is it because I need to add the markers in OnCreateView?

```
 public class MapUserFragment extends SupportMapFragment
 {
      public MapUserFragment() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater arg0, ViewGroup arg1, Bundle arg2) {
        View v = super.onCreateView(arg0, arg1, arg2);
        initMap();
        return v;
    }

    private void initMap(){
        LatLng lat = new LatLng(0, 0);
        UiSettings settings = getMap().getUiSettings();
        settings.setAllGesturesEnabled(false);
        settings.setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);

       // getMap().moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(lat,16));
        getMap().addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(lat));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Exactly, now You are calling `initMap()` <- method which is invoke in `onCreateView`. Before you tried to create marker in `SupportMapFragment`. This method is called before map is created,  even before `onCreate`
[Here you can read more about it](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/SupportMapFragment.html#onActivityCreated%28android.os.Bundle%29)